# WaitForSingleObject and mailslot IPC

Tags: winapi, visual-studio-2008

I have two programs: MailSlot_server and Mailslot_client.

Mailslot_server create a mailslot and read message from this mailslot. Mailslot_client writes message to the mailslot at any moment.

Now, in Mailslot_server program, i have to use a thread to read message from mailslot.
This is function executed by thread.

```
while (TRUE)
{
    DWORD msgSize = 0;

    Sleep(1000);
    result = GetMailslotInfo(hSlot, 0, &msgSize, 0, 0);

    if (result == FALSE)
    {
        printf("GetMailslotInfo failed with error %d\n", GetLastError());
        continue;
    }

    if (msgSize != (DWORD)MAILSLOT_NO_MESSAGE)
    {
        char buffer[1024] = {0};
        DWORD numRead = 0;

        result = ReadFile(hSlot, buffer, msgSize, &numRead, 0);
        if (!result) 
        {
            printf("ReadFile error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        }
        else if (msgSize != numRead) 
        {
            printf("ReadFile did not read the correct number of bytes!");
        }
        else
        {
                            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

I do not need to use Sleep() function. Do you have any suggestion? can i use WaitForSingleObject() function to know when mailslot has message.

Comment: *Nobody* uses mail slots, they are completely useless.  Lots of good examples on how to implement an asynchronous pipe server around.

Comment: But in the case multi-client and a server. I don't want to create new pipe. I use mailslot to many clients can write message in the mailslot and server can read all messages from it.

Comment: A mail slot has no delivery guarantee, it will randomly drop messages whenever it feels like it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You will need to create a named event using [`CreateEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in your server and then use [`OpenEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684305%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the client to get a handle to it.

So, in the server:

```
// create an auto-reset event
m_hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, _T("SomeUniqueName"));

// ... when you have written a mailslot message ...
SetEvent(m_hEvent);

// on shut down
CloseHandle(m_hEvent);
```

And in the client:

```
// get a handle to the server's event
m_hEvent = OpenEvent(SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, _T("SomeUniqueName"));

// main loop
while (/* not time to exit */)
{
    // wait for signal
    WaitForSingleObject(m_hEvent, INFINITE);

    // ... read from mailslot ....
}
```

You'll need to add some error checking and make sure you close all handles you opened. Also, you may need a second event just within the client so you can signal the thread to close tidily (although you can also `SetEvent` from the main thread in the client to force it round the loop).

Comment: Oh, there is a little misunderstanding. In your example, server will write message to the mailslot and client reads message. But my problem is server need to read message. However, I think it is good solution, thanks!

Comment: @quangdien Sorry, my mistake! Just make sure that whichever runs first creates the event and the other opens it. If necessary, you can code around it in both sides by trying the open first and then create if the open failed. That way it won't matter which starts first.

Comment: I have new question. In case there are many clients and one server, I have to create many event corresponding with many clients or only use one event?

Comment: @quangdien Assuming the server owns and reads the mailslot, it should create the event and and all clients can open event and set it. It can be the same event. Also, you should be aware that the mailslot can be created to wait indefinitely on a read so there is a wait process already built in if you want to use it.

Comment: yes, I know that the mailslot can wait forever and I set this argument in CreateMailslot function. However, I don't find any function that can read message from mailslot and block thread until it returns value. This is why I must use Sleep() to decrease the using of pc resource(ex: CPU).

Comment: @quangdien Ok, I understand. In my apps I use a timer to periodically check the mailslot - Sleep in a separate thread is probably just as effective, there should be little overhead reading from an empty mailslot.

Comment: May you have any suggestion about using timer, my application is win32 console.SetTimer is only available for GUI application.

Comment: @quangdien For a console app, a background thread is a better option. For a GUI app, using a timer is easier, although a separate thread may still be better - it depends on the workflow. Timers suits my workflow, it may not suit other situations.

Comment: @RogerRowland: Just a note about your comment of the first program to run creating the event, and the other opening... `CreateEvent` will open an existing named event, so if all programs use that API call, the first to run will create it anyway. Saves trying to sort out the ordering yourself :)